# Getting Addresses From a database into a google map

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3, mysqli

I am currently working on a search system where after searching for a certain home It will display the search results and have the addresses of the search results show up the google map api.

I manage to display multiple addresses in google map via array but right now I'm inputting the address manually.  How can I put the addresses I have in the database into this array.

here is the google map code note that var locations is the variable containing the array of addresses

```
var locations = ['250 - 13450 102 Avenue Surrey, BC', '8888 University Dr Burnaby, BC', '35-160 Pembina St.New Westminster, BC'];
                function geocodeAddress(i) {
                    geocoder.geocode(
                                    {
                                        'address' : locations[i]
                                    },
                                    function(results, status) {
                                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                                            createMarker(results[0].geometry.location, i);
                                        } else {
                                            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: '
                                                    + status);
                                        }
                                    });
        }
```

here is the php part

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","", "");
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
        }
///////////set variables

$sql = $mysqli->query("select * from propertyinfo");
```

also i tried this on var locations

```
var locations = ['<?php 
                    while ($row = $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    echo ''.$row['StreetAddress'].', '.$row['City'].', BC, ';}
                    ?>'];
```

I cant seem to get heads or tails on this not sure if i should use json_encode or something . Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid putting PHP logic directly into the output like that. It's just messy, and makes working with the code more difficult than it has to be. Do the logic in PHP first, and then put it into the output.

In your case, create the location array first in PHP, and then translate that PHP array into the desired output format when needed.

```
<?php
$locations = array();
while ($row = $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $locations[] = $row["StreetAddress"] . ", " . $row["City"] . ", BC";
}
?>

var locations = ['<?php implode("', '", $locations); ?>'];
```